# VB SQL error: The instruction INSERT contains a syntax error

Tags: sql, vb.net, com

I'm woking on a project with a database, and I'm trying to create a row in my table, using the following query:

```
"INSERT INTO USERCOINFO (username, company, streetAddress, postalCode, language, department, postOfficeBox, country, telephoneNumber, faxNumber, title, givenName, surname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

the values are filled by the following variables using

```
Dim dbInsert As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim objClient = GetObject(objRecordSet.Fields("ADsPath").Value)

Dim username = objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value
Dim company = objClient.company
Dim streetAddress = objClient.streetAddress
Dim postalCode = objClient.postalCode
Dim lo = objClient.lo
Dim department = objClient.department
Dim postOfficeBox = objClient.postOfficeBox
Dim country = objClient.co
Dim telephoneNumber = objClient.telephoneNumber
Dim faxNumber = objClient.facsimiletelephonenumber
Dim title = objClient.title
Dim givenName = objClient.givenName
Dim surname = objClient.sn
```

and then I bind them with:

```
dbInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", username)
dbInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", company)
'and so on...
```

to my knownlege, this is correct, but it still returns a syntax error:
`The instruction INSERT contains a syntax error.`

Comment: You need to include the param names in your values section of the insert. For example: `VALUES (@etc, @etc2)`... Right now your query is unaware of the params... Also avoid `AddWithValue` use `Add` and specify the SQL DataType...

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry, my bad, thought this was obvous because of the title, I added it to the bottom of the question

Comment: @Zaggler I've done this for 2 other tables so far, and it works, so I don't know why this wouldn't work this way

Comment: Then try it, what happens? Also don't blindly rely on non-specified params, declare and use them that is why they are there...

Comment: @Zaggler I just did, no result, note that the error occurs before the `VALUES` are added

Comment: did you try doing this directly and see what happens?

Comment: @Zaggler yes, that's what I just said

Comment: Im talking about doing it directly in the DB with the values you are using.

Comment: @Zaggler this database has been created using VB and yes, all the params are declared, because if not declared, it won't even append the tables to the database...

Comment: Zaggler is saying if you paste in dummy values to your query in place of your ? placeholders, does it work within SQL Server or whatever database you are using?

Comment: @topshot this results in the same error, ofcourse, because of the fact that the error is found in the INSERT statement and not in the VALUE statement. please, remember this, if the error was in the data being added, it would give a VALUE syntax error

Comment: Try using a `SELECT` instead of `VALUES`... For example: `INSERT INTO USERCOINFO (username, company, streetAddress, postalCode, language, department, postOfficeBox, country, telephoneNumber, faxNumber, title, givenName, surname) SELECT 'something', 'somethingelse' etc...` Also please post full code for executing this statement...

Comment: @Zaggler this results in the same error, ofcourse, because of the fact that the error is found in the INSERT statement and not in the VALUE statement. please, remember this, if the error was in the data being added, it would give a VALUE syntax error

Comment: That is exactly the point we're making. You need to fix your `INSERT` statement. It has nothing to do with VB at this point. For all we know, you have a simple typo or data type mismatch, but you didn't provide the table definition.

Comment: @topshot I checked this multiple times, it's not because of a typo, because I coppied the table and column names directly from the database itself

Comment: Then paste the exact statement you are using to test within the db itself. And verify which db that is since you didn't tag it.

Comment: Not sure if you are using MySQL, but if you are, `language` is a reserved word.  Try `[language]`.

Comment: @JimHewitt though I'm not using MySQL, this was indeed the problem, thanks for the suggestion, I'll write it down in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated in the comments and suggested by Jim Hewitt, it was indeed the usuage of a syntax word in the column declaration in the statement, I've changed the column name to something else to further reduce confusion from language to CoLanguage. everything is now working.

thanks to all the people who were willing to help be with this.

Meep,
Luuk

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"INSERT INTO USERCOINFO (username, company, streetAddress, postalCode, language, department, postOfficeBox, country, telephoneNumber, faxNumber, title, givenName, surname) VALUES (?username, ?company, ?streetAddress, ?postalCode, ?language, ?department, ?postOfficeBox, ?country, ?telephoneNumber, ?faxNumber, ?title, ?givenName, ?surname)"

Dim dbInsert As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim objClient = GetObject(objRecordSet.Fields("ADsPath").Value)

Dim username = objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value
Dim company = objClient.company
Dim streetAddress = objClient.streetAddress
Dim postalCode = objClient.postalCode
Dim lo = objClient.l
Dim department = objClient.department
Dim postOfficeBox = objClient.postOfficeBox
Dim country = objClient.co
Dim telephoneNumber = objClient.telephoneNumber
Dim faxNumber = objClient.facsimiletelephonenumber
Dim title = objClient.title
Dim givenName = objClient.givenName
Dim surname = objClient.sn

dbInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
dbInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", company)
```